# "gets" breaks in C with a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, gets

If the while loop continues "gets(purpose); just gets skipped after the first loop

```
    while(finish==0){
printf("PASSWORD LAB EL?? WHAT IS IT??\n:");
gets(purpose);
printf("Put lth the length (LESS THAN 2048)\n:");
scanf("%d", &length);
if(length<=2048){
passwords = fopen("password.txt","a");
fprintf(passwords,"%s:\n", purpose);
    for(length; length>0; length--){
        int bruh = rand() % 78;
        printf("%c", words[bruh]);  
        fprintf(passwords,"%c", words[bruh]);
    finish = 1;
    }
}else{
    printf("TOO MUCH LAWL\n\n");
    system("clear");
    finish = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `gets` is a deprecated function, just so you know.

Comment: How do I get rid of that newline?

Comment: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != ’\n’) ;`